# Avoiding GCC compiler warning "return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type"

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, constants, return-value

I have the following function:

```
item *already_met_the_number(const item *p, long n)
{
    while (p) {
        if (p->num == n)
            return p;
        else
            p = p->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I don't want the data structure to be changed in the function. However later I change the  returned item.
I get the following warning from `gcc` compiler:
`warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type`
How should I rewrite my function following good programming practices?

Comment: Why can't you use consistent constness in parameter and return type?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Because it's not actually constant, but they want to avoid accidentally changing the pointed thing in the function ("I don't want the data structure to be changed in the function"). Personally, I think this is overly paranoid, and the `const` should be removed rather than lying to the users about it being a const pointer.

Comment: @ikegami Even if they're being paranoid, there's still a sane alternative: you add `const` to both places, then make a second non-const overload that uses `const_cast`s to call the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I rewrite my function following good programming practices?

By removing the `const`.

> I don't want the data structure to be changed in the function.

You don't need the compiler's help for that.

Long answer follows.

---

Let's look at another function for a second, one that returns a pointer to the NUL of a string.

```c
const char *s1b = "abc";
const char *s1e = end_of( s1b );

char s2b[] = "def";
char *s2e = end_of( s2b );
```

How would we implement this function so that it works with both `const` and non-`const` data (as shown)?

Well, C doesn't permit that.<sup>[1]</sup> We've seen the following approximation:

```c
char *end_of( const char *s ) {
   while ( *s ) ++s;
   return ( char * )s;
}
```

The above snippet now works. However, our function also silently allows the following:

```c
const char *s3b = "ghi";
char *s3e = end_of( s3b );  // `*s3e` isn't actually modifiable.
```

Imperfect, but good enough.

---

But that's not the situation being asked about here.

The concept of a linked list with unmodifiable nodes makes no sense. You require a modifiable pointer since you return a modifiable pointer. So we're talking about temporarily using a `const` pointer for non-`const` data.

The best practice would be to not lie to the caller about being able to accept a `const` pointer.

```c
item *already_met_the_number( item *p, long n ) {
   while ( p ) {
      if ( p->num == n )
         return p;
      else
         p = p->next;
   }

   return NULL;
}
```

---

But what about using a non-parameter `const` variable and casting the result?

```c
item *already_met_the_number( item *p_noconst, long n ) {
   const item *p = p_noconst;
   while ( p ) {
      if ( p->num == n )
         return ( item * )p;
      else
         p = p->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

An explicit cast is one of the most dangerous things in C. Especially a pointer cast. It's so easy to get wrong, or to become wrong as code is maintained, and it can be silent as the very point of the cast is to override safety features.

Adding this second variable and a cast simply makes this function more complex and more dangerous. This is a not a good practice, at least not here.

---

1. Well, it's now possible using a macro and `_Generic`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cast to indicate the conversion is deliberate:

`return (item *) p;`

The need for this is a shortcoming in the C language, in part because `const` was added to the language late.

Comment: I disagree. `*p` is not modifiable, but you want to make it modifiable when returned from the function. A bit of inconsistency.

Comment: @0___________: You disagree with what? You show the same solution in your answer.

Comment: That it is a `shortcoming in the C language`

Comment: @0___________: It is a shortcoming; the author wants to denote that the object(s) pointed to by a parameter are not modified in the function but that the return value provides a pointer that can be used to modify the objects, and the C standard does not provide a way of doing this. Since this is lacking in the standard, it is a deficiency.

Comment: In your code example if you try to pass a reference to `const` object it will emit another warning.

Comment: @0___________: Yes, that is why it is an alternative, not a solution.

Comment: `return p_without_const;` seems wrong. `p_without_const` is the original, unchanged pointer, but you want to return the one that points to the right object, which is `p`. So I think you need `return (item *)p;`, with an explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1. The cast

```
            return (item *)p;
```

2. Using pragmas

```
            #pragma GCC diagnostic push
            #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdiscarded-qualifiers"
            return p;
            #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

3. Combination of macro and function

```
#define already_met_the_number(ptr, num) already_met_the_number_fuction((item *)(ptr), (num))

item *already_met_the_number_fuction(item *p, long n)
{
    while (p) {
        if (p->num == n)
            return p;
        else
            p = p->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Basically, this function is inconsistent and the warning is correct. Often parameters are `const` to prevent warning when you pass const object or reference to the const object and the function is taking non const parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do not want to "cast away const", since what will happen when doing so isn't really covered by the C standard. The 6.3.2.3 chapter regarding pointer conversions doesn't mention what will happen when you do a pointer conversion that discards qualifiers.

With that in mind, the function should perhaps have been designed differently, using different types for the parameters. That's the best solution here.

If that isn't possible, you could for example check against `p->next` instead, something like this:

```
// First check that the current node isn't a null pointer, then:

while (p->next) {
    if (p->next->num == n)
        return p->next;
  ...
```

This uses a cheeky trick, namely:

- By de-referencing `p` we get a `const item` where each member gets `const` "added to it" for the duration of the expression.
- So if you have a member like `struct item* next;`, de-referencing a `const item` will make this member get treated like `struct item* const next;`. A read-only pointer to read/write data.
- It is fine to assign a `item* const` to a `item*` for the same reason as it is fine to assign a `const int` to an `int`, "lvalue conversion" will happen.
- But it is not fine to do as in the original code, assign a `const item*` to an `item*` because here the `const` belongs to the pointed-at type.

An even cheekier but not really recommended alternative would be to union type pun between two pointer types, const and non-const, instead of a cast. I really doubt it makes any difference in practice compared with a "dirty" cast, so I won't post such a solution.

Also there's upcoming C23 `typeof_unqual` which allows yet another questionable solution: `typeof_unqual(*p)* ptr;`.

Comment: The problem is that it will no change anything if `const struct item* next`

Comment: @0___________ How exactly would you meaningfully use a linked list built on `const` qualified `next` pointers?